# C++ unix 32bit to Red Hat Linux running on an x86_64 chip (64-bit server)

Tags: c++, linux, 64-bit

I am working on a project that is porting application in C++ from 32 bit unix to Red Hat Linux running on an x86_64 chip (64-bit server). I am facing issues related to long data types.I wrote a sample program to print  a binary long and unsigned long value of 1. This has an extra 1 in middle:

ul = 0000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000001
l = 0000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000001

```
string binary(unsigned long i)   
{   
int n = sizeof(unsigned long);  
string s;  
n *= 8;  
--n;  
while (n >= 0)   
{  
unsigned long mask = (1 << n);   
s += (mask & i ? "1" : "0");   
--n;  
}   
return s;  
}   
string binary(long i)  
{  
int n = sizeof( long);   
string s;   
n *= 8;  
--n;  
while (n >= 0)  
{   
long mask = (1 << n);   
s += (mask & i ? "1" : "0");  
--n;   
}   
return s;  
}   
int main()  
{  
unsigned long ul = 1;  
long l = 1;    
cout << "sizeof ul = " << sizeof ul <<  ", ul = "  <<ul<<  endl;   
cout << "sizeof l = "  << sizeof l  << ", l = " << l << endl;    
cout << "ul = " << binary(ul) << endl;   
cout << "l = "  << binary(l) << endl;    
return 0;  
}
```

As you all can see I am not getting why there is an extra 1 IN MIDDLE. This is causing run time issues in my application. Please let me know.
I am getting extra 1 middle in Red Hat Linux running on an x86_64 chip (64-bit server) not in unix and that is the cause of run time issues. Any idea please let me know.

Comment: `enter code here` is meant to be replaced by your code...

Comment: And are you sure your `long` has 64bit? It would make sense if it has 32...

Comment: That´s not complete. If you already made a short sample program which shows the problem, please post all of it so that we can check it.

Comment: @deviantfan I have entered it Please have a look. Moreover sizeof operator returned 8 bytes for ong and ulong.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
unsigned long mask = (1 << n);
```

Apparently, a `unsigned long` has 8 byte and a normal `int` has 4 byte on your system.

Here you have a `int` with value 1 (every literal value is `int` if nothing else is explicitely specified). You´re doing the shifting on this 4 byte `int`, and **then** the result is converted to 8 byte to save it in `mask`. Shifting more than 31 bit is too much in 4 byte, yet you´re doing it until 63 bit.

To solve the problem, you have to tell the compiler that `1` is meant a 8 byte `unsigned long`.
Three possibilites:

```
unsigned long mask = (1UL << n);  
//or
unsigned long mask = ((unsigned long)1 << n);  
//or just
unsigned long mask = 1;  
mask = mask << n;
```

The other function (for the signed type) has the same problem.
With the first variant, use just `L` there, without `U`.

Comment: Thank you. I have one more doubt than. If I have a variable in const long say l1 and a variable in ushort say us1. Now I need to compare these two say if( l1 != us1) .... this is not working. What typecasting should I use ?. This piece worked in 32 bit unix but works unpredictably  in linux 64 bit. The reason in number of bits occupied by long is changed now. I am planning to convert us1 to long and then compare. say (l1 != (ulong)us1). But again in this l1 will be signed .

Comment: @ShefaliSrivastava The short is automatically converted to long before comparing, 32/64bit doesn´t matter at all here. The signed problem does matter, but this is not new with 64bit, you had the same problem with 32bit too.

Comment: it was working perfectly in 32 bit since 1995. It is not working in LINUX 64 bit machine. 1 variable is a USHORT CORBA variable and other is a const long. I believe while converting from USHORT to long some garbage value might come.

Comment: @ShefaliSrivastava This can´t be (except for the mentioned signedness problem, which means wrong code in the first place). There has to be something wrong in your code. Maybe you should make a new post (with code again).